# Single word request for ability to reject spurious hypothesis

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm writing: "(...) in this way, we compromise precision, and the ability to reject spurious hypothesis (...)".

I'm looking for something like: "in this way, we compromise precision, and ***_*_**".

Comment: There is no single word that specifically means “the ability to reject spurious hypotheses”—why on earth would there be? Not all spurious hypotheses should be rejected, while quite a few non-spurious ones should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual answer is *discrimination* ("the perceiving, noting, or making a distinction or difference between things...the power of observing differences accurately, or of making exact distinctions", OED) but in non-technical contexts this has acquired such negative associations that you have to be very careful.

Answer (score 1):

This suggestion may not be narrow enough in scope, but *discretion* is what springs immediately to mind.

[discretion](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/discretion) - the freedom to decide what should be done in a particular situation

> in this way, we compromise precision and discretion

Comment: No need for the comma after *precision*.

Comment: @JLG You might want to tell that to the OP.

Comment: @JLG I have removed the comma.  Thanks for helping me to improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Some possibilities are:

- ***caution*** (we don't want to make a wrong decision)
- ***exactness*** or ***exactitude***
- ***rigor*** (we want to examine things closely enough to make an informed decision)
- ***skepticism*** (we maintain doubt until we see positive signs)